# Removing Windows and redundant partitions and increasing Ubuntu partition size

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, gparted

I have a dual-boot Windows and Ubuntu system, however, I want to remove the Windows partition since I do not use it. I previously had dual boot and I unfortunately broke it and had to start again with a new partition.

I would also like to remove the previous Ubuntu partition since I cannot access it anymore and I have all that I need in my current Ubuntu partition, I'm just beginning to run out of space so would like to expand it.

[image: GParted view of partitions]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resize partitions?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/126153/how-to-resize-partitions)